# Matplotlib TypeError: PlotAccessor.pie() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, typeerror, pie-chart

I just started with Python to learn how to be a Data Analyst and now I am learning about plots using matplotlib on jupyter notebook.

When I try to run this piece of code that you will find also on the bottom

```
pop_by_region.plot.pie("Population",
                      figsize = (8, 8))
plt.show()
```

it also gives me error on the last piece of code:

```
pop_by_region.plot.pie("Population",
                      figsize = (8, 8),
                      legends = False,
                      cmap = "Set3")

plt.show()
```

same error

it gives me the TypeError that is on the title. I read somewhere that it's because I am not defining the method and that is why it happens but I am unsure on how to do that or if that really is the solution, I have been stuck on this for 4 days already and I cannot find the answer, I wonder if someone could help me please.

I pasted the whole code so you can see everything.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

required_cols =["Country",
               "Region",
               "Population",
               "Coastline (coast/area ratio)",
               "GDP ($ per capita)",
               "Literacy (%)",
               "Birthrate"]

countries = pd.read_csv("datasets/countries_of_the_world.csv",
                       usecols = required_cols,
                       decimal = ",")

countries.rename(columns = {"GDP ($ per capita)": "PerCapitaGDP",
                           "Coastline (coast/area ratio)" : "CoastLineAreaRatio",
                           "Literacy (%)" : "LiteracyRate"},
                 inplace = True)

countries = countries.dropna()

countries.head()

countries.Region.unique()

avg_by_region = countries.groupby(by = "Region").mean()

avg_by_region

avg_by_region.Birthrate.plot(kind = "bar")

plt.show()

avg_by_region.Birthrate.plot(kind = "barh",
                            title = "Avg. Birthrate by Region")
plt.show()

pop_by_region = countries[["Region", "Population"]].groupby(by = "Region").sum()



pop_by_region.plot.pie("Population",
                      figsize = (8, 8))
plt.show()

pop_by_region.plot.pie("Population",
                      figsize = (8, 8),
                      legends = False,
                      cmap = "Set3")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html), the `dataframe.plot.pie()` method only accepts keyword arguments (`**kwargs`), while you are specifying the column to plot as a positional argument. So you just need to prefix your column label with `y=`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['US','Canada','Mexico'], 'Population': [331, 37, 128]})

df.plot.pie(y="Population", figsize = (8, 8), labels=df.Country)
plt.show()
```

[image]